# Why do i got minus with filter rows age > 0 in pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Hello i'm currently learning pentaho, and i used a filter rows
And when i'm using the filter rows condition like this : Age > 0
What i got was only the minus in the preview. I thought Age > 0 it should've been a more than 1 right?
When i used Age < 0, it only got positives numbers not minus. Why ?

[job picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy4YZ.png)

[data preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8S2f.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Filter Rows" step has 2 option. One is what do you want if condition is "**true**" and another is what do you want if condition is "**false**".

[image]

In your transformation, you have choose option 'false'. That's why all rows are selected which are <0. You need to select step "Calculator" in 'Send **true** data to step' box as you want result if condition true.

You can see sample from [HERE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10rmWDDWN1LVNR8i0g3K5CaxZqCh9dGbG?usp=sharing) in Logging preview.